# how can I use encoding URIbuilder() method in Java

Tags: java, url, encoding, uri, encode

I'm using some API in JAVA.

I need to use Korean text in URI, and request is the String variable.
If I set `request = "안녕하세요";` and i use the code:

```
final URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https").setHost(server + "api.net").setPath("/api/" + "/" + **request**).setParameters(param).build(). ;
```

If I use this, I can see this following result:

> https://api.net/api/%EC%95%88%EB%85%95%ED%95%98%EC%84%B8%EC%9A%94?api_key

I already tried to use this code:

```
final URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https").setHost(server + "api.net").setPath("/api/" + "/" + **URLEncoder.encode(request, "UTF-8")**).setParameters(param).build(). ;
```

but I am getting the same result.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URI has been encoded. As like URL, you can't use special characters, if you want to retrieve `request` string, you must decode that specific part of your URI, something like this:

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(uri.getPath(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(result);          // this will print "/api/안녕하세요"
```

The [RFC 3986, Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) confirms it:

> A URI is a sequence of characters from a    very limited set: the
>   letters of the basic Latin alphabet, digits,    and a few special
>   characters.

Later it says:

> Percent-encoded octets [...] may be used within a URI to
>   represent characters outside the range of the US-ASCII coded character
>   set if this representation is allowed by the scheme or by the protocol
>   element in which the URI is referenced.

Which is the bunch of characters that you are getting.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks very much! i also got other route..
final URI uri2 = new URI( uri.getScheme() + "://" + uri.getHost() + uri.getPath() + "?" + uri.getQuery());

Comment: i don't know why no break text , but i think more better than my code, really Thanks!!